# Cannot apply CSS to <Switch disable>

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to apply css style to a `<Switch disabled>` in order to make the `<Switch>`:

1. have normal color
2. cannot interact with user

I have try to apply the css using the following code.

Demo sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-panini-fdvdg?file=/src/App.js

> ```
> <FormControlLabel
>     control={
>       <Switch
>         color="secondary"
>         checked
>         disabled
>         classes={{ disabled: classes.disabled }}
>       />
>     }
>     label={"Disabled"}
>   />
> ```

But, end up, the style is overrided by other CSS

[image]

So, how can I apply the css to that component?

Comment: This is a very basic problem in CSS. To solve it you have at least 2 options. 1. Write a more specific selector like `.grandParent .parent .element { styles } ` . 2 . This is ONLY as a last resort. use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You can see what more specific selector is overwriting that one by right clicking it and selecting view computed value